# System.UnexpectedException: Read of id returned an invalid id '000000000000000'

Tags: unit-test, exception, apex-sharing, summer14

Since a few days ago a some methods in one test class started to fail with this exception

> System.UnexpectedException: Read of id returned an invalid id
>   '000000000000000'

What is more interesting is that this code has not been modified for months, and is completely data independent. It seems to coincide with the summer '14 /API 31.0 release (possibly a bug?).

The line that is failing is the query which I am using for asserting that either a record sharing row has been created or not.

```
Boolean AnotherUserHasAccess=[SELECT RecordId,HasReadAccess FROM UserRecordAcces WHERE RecordID=:HelloQuickTxt AND UserID=:SalesUser2.Id].HasReadAccess;
```

Notice that both variables used in the query are returning a valid id according to the debug log so I don't understand what is causing this issue.

Furthermore, I tried to handle the exception but it doesn't seem to be possible.

I will be opening a case with Salesforce but I am posting this in case anyone is also experiencing this issue or knows what is it about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce support got back to me saying this is a bug on their query optimizer and as a workaround the LIMIT clause can be added to the query.